# Working of control system of an elevator?

Tags: control, system

I am interested in studying/learning how control system of an elevator works.?How its specs/parameters are controlled or adjusted? Especially rise time and steady state error.?to provide comfortable experience for humans inside the elevator so they do not experience oscillations or high speed(abnormal rise time) and other issues

Elevators use only proportional controllers or pi controllers or pid controllers?

I couldn't find a satisfactory link after Google search so i thought to ask it on ee stack exchange

Comment: nothing so complex you will find in elevator.

Comment: I would just assume proportional. Elevators never do feel very smooth to me.

Comment: I don't think that there is any one design. A basic elevator for a low-rise building probably runs the motor at full speed while travelling. A modern elevator for a high-rise building may use constant acceleration to reach a fairly high maximum velocity, then start decelerating well before it reaches the final floor.

Comment: @Mattman944 like a starship? vroom vroom

Comment: For a position controlled servo motor, you have three control loops. The innermost controls the motor current (and thus the torque), the second controls the velocity and the outermost is your position controller. Yes, this can be quite sophisticated, but you can by these "servo motors" from the shelf. https://www.motioncontroltips.com/servo-drive-loops/

Comment: @DKNguyen - Just saying that most of the elevators that I use are slow and jerky, but I have also been on elevators that are surprisingly fast and smooth. The later having a complex control system; the former having a minimal control system, maybe almost none, just a low speed for final positioning (limit switches?).

Comment: @Mattman944 Well, I'm talking about your common elevator. I'm sure hundred story skyrises are different.

Answer (score 1):

Probably at least P+I control to get ~0 error at the floor positioning.

Self-tuning PID or fuzzy logic for higher performance. Plus some clever scheduling and positioning logic to optimize the use of multiple elevators.

The classic control system used in early elevators is the [Ward-Leonard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_Leonard_control), which uses no electronics, just a M-G set. Diagram from [here](https://www.electrical4u.com/ward-leonard-method-of-speed-control/)

Changing the current in the generator field winding acts to control the speed and direction of motor rotation.

[image]